# Catch image data via WI-FI

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, wifi

I have a device that takes pictures and send to an iPhone app via WI-FI.
The iPhone has to connect to the device's WIFI, and when the device takes a picture it saves to camera roll of the iPhone if the app is in the foreground. However if the app is in the background, nothing happens.

My question is, can I catch this image data with another app that I create? I assume the data arrives to the iPhone via WI-FI when the app is in the background also.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please mention what app and device are you using? Is device<->iOS app link using some proprietary protocol?

Comment: This is the device and the app:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zoomx/id843663828

Comment: You can try to intercept app's data using tools like Charles and inspect how it works and then try to simulate the host.